# Stop sharing a port on Ngrok

Tags: ngrok

The [Ngrok documentation](https://ngrok.com/usage) mentions this example to share a local port on Internet.
Example: Open port 80 on your local machine to the internet

```
$ ngrok 80
```

How do I stop sharing this port if I would not want it to be accessed on the internet any more>

Answer (score 46):

On windows machine go to command prompt:

```
taskkill /f /im ngrok.exe
```

Answer (score 25):

`killall ngrok` from a script or the command line will kill all running ngrok tunnels that are running.

This is what worked for me. Ty @kkron.

Answer (score 11):

First, you have to find the `ngrok process id` by `$ top` command.
After that, just run `$ kill -9 {ngrok_id}`
That's all :)

Answer (score 10):

## Stopping the ngrok port/tunnel

### Simple Solution

1. If you are running ngrok normally, then use **Ctrl+C** (On Windows) or **Cmd+C** (On Mac) in ngrok command line.
   (Check below if issue still persist)

### Extended Solution

2. If the port does not stop/close normally or there are active ngrok sessions that are not responding, then use: ***killall ngrok***
3. If the above does not work or the port is still running,

- Fix ngrok in your system by setting up your auth code again by logging into https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started
- Generate a new token on the dashboard (scroll down dashboard) to https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started/your-authtoken
- Click on "reset authtoken", copy the auth-code, then go-to **ngrok** on command-line ***ngrok authtoken INSERT-YOUR-NEW-TOKEN-HERE***
- Then go to ngrok folder or use command line to delete the .ngrok configuration file and directory: ***ngrok.yml***, to remove the old configuration effectively ending all the open ports, tunnels and sessions.

Answer (score 7):

Simple as pressing ctrl+c. But I'm not sure if it closes any ports. The same happens as @user7032676 told.
[image]

Answer (score 6):

I've figured out another simple solution.

Just go to your ngrok dashboard-> Tunnels-> Agents.

Then click on the agent you want to stop and stop it from there.

Or you could restart the agent from there, which will trigger a terminal session to open on your laptop.
You can now use cmd+c to quit that session and that will stop the tunnel

Answer (score 4):

Quick search process with grep

```sh
top | grep "ngrok"
```

My id was this, make sure to change with yours

```sh
kill -9 55636
```

If you like start again tunneling from working directory

```
ngrok http 3000
```

Answer (score 3):

You just have to stop ngrok for this.

Comment: And how would that be on a Mac? Pardon the naivety, never worked with Ngrok

Comment: I use linux, but i think is the same on mac. If you start it from the console you just have to hit Ctrl+C to stop it. Otherwise yo have to see find the process in the process list and kill it.

Comment: killall ngrok

from a script or the command line will kill all running ngrok tunnels that are running.

Comment: for Mac: `ps -A` to see all processes, then `kill XXXX`, replacing XXXX with the number of the ngrok process.

Answer (score 1):

You should see `(CTRL+C to quit)` on the top right corner of your terminal, when you are running a ngrok session (Online).

Although in my case, `CTRL+C` wasn't working. Instead `CTRL+ALT+C` did the quitting for me.

Operating System: `Ubuntu 20.04`

Answer (score 1):

For some reason whenever I launched the ngrok agent on windows, the terminal will shutdown and not stay open. I would have to go to the website to see the url for the website.
To shut it down I could not do `ctrl-c`. I simply went into task manager and deleted the process.
To access the task manager on windows do `ctrl + alt + delete`

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to stop ngrok tunnel without killing the process directly. You can use ngrok agent api: https://ngrok.com/docs/ngrok-agent/api/

Just send DELETE request to http://127.0.0.1:4040/api/tunnels/:your_tunnel_name

```
curl -X DELETE http://127.0.0.1:4040/api/tunnels/:your_tunnel_name
```

You can get information about running tunnels using api too. For example,

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:4040/api/tunnels
```

will return list of running tunnels

Answer (score -5):

Reboot the computer and all. Hope helped

Comment: Rebooting the computer just to shutdown a service is not really a solution...

Comment: Sorry, but it worked for me. I have Windows.

Comment: I shot my CPU. Thanks for the inspiration.